# Replacing A Stuck MetaMask Transaction With Something Other Than 0ETH To Yourself

Tags: metamask

I tried to send ETH from one of my wallets to another, but I set the gas too low & it's been stuck (pending) for days. I understand that the typical way to 'un-stick' such a transaction is to replace it by sending a 0 ETH transaction to yourself, with higher gas, and setting the nonce to same as the 'stuck' transaction - like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivCPlz2P2mE.

Every example I've seen about "un-sticking" ETH transactions *always* does so by sending 0ETH back to yourself. Would this work just as well with a different type of ETH transaction? For example, could I just replace it with a transaction sending some ETH from my wallet1 to wallet2, as I was originally trying to do? Or it should only be replaced with 0eth sent back to myself?

Comment: Can you do something like that with the failed opensea transaction? opensea recently get ETH out of my wallet and failed and the whole amount doesn’t come back to my wallet what can I DO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to send 0 eth to yourself to replace your transaction. Any transaction that has the following characteristics would work:

1. It comes from the same address;
2. It has the same nonce; and
3. It has a gas price at least 10% higher than the previous gas price.

Comment: Thank for the quick reply.  Just to be sure - are you 100% certain? :)  Also, just out of personal curiosity, why 10% higher?  I'm fine with that, just curious about the number - i.e. is that somehow built into the protocol, or is that just a sensible guideline to try to get it approved quicker?

Comment: I am certain. The 10% threshold is set by the miners. They could set a lower or higher threshold to accept a replacing transaction, but by default Geth sets it to 10%, so I would go with that.

Comment: Interesting.  I would've thought that the highest one would just get mined (since it's more profitable) & the lower one thus dropped.  I'll do the 10%, but out of curiosity, what happens if you go lower?  Once the gas prices eventually drop below i.e. the gas price on the first transaction, that one would be mined, despite there being another one with, say, 5% higher gas?

Comment: This never happened to me, but presumably yes, the old transaction would be mined. It is also possible that some miners accept the transaction with the highest gas price even if it is less than 10% (miners can change the default setting).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks again.  I did it with >10% & worked perfectly :)